# Question about how a website *might* have implemented something?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

This ([How does Twitch keep a persistent video window over several pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286748/how-does-twitch-keep-a-persistent-video-window-over-several-pages)) feels off-topic and my immediate reaction was to vote-close. However, I can't find a suitable option and it's getting quite a bit of attention.

What to do?

Comment: Too broad or opinion based.

Comment: @Stijn I'm answering the title.

Comment: @Stijn It would be in any platform where you didn't have access to the source code, which is basically all of them except for the front end of a webpage, as you'd just be guessing at how a given product implemented the feature.

Answer (score 17):

Well, in this specific case, the only real consideration would be the possibility of it being, "too broad".

In general though, the question can be trivially rephrased to just ask, "How could I do X?" rather than, "How did someone else do X?"  You can then follow that question up by saying, "I found someone that did X, just like I want to do, but I don't understand how they did it."  Now, in this particular case, what it's asking seems rather broad, but in other similarly templated questions, it may well be quite specific.

Comment: So this is in fact a "good", or perhaps let's called it _valid_ instead, question?

Comment: @Yuck I would say it's a pattern that could be easily refactored into one that's perfectly acceptable.  [if you don't refactor it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340162/question-about-how-a-website-might-have-implemented-something/340163?noredirect=1#comment424355_340162) then it has problems.

Comment: If it's not too broad , I would go with a a request for an off-site resource. The information is there, the asker just hasn't looked.

Comment: @Paulie_D They're *not* requesting an off site resource though.  As to whether or not the question is well researched, that's entirely independent of whether or not the question is in this form.  You can ask a poorly researched or a well researched, "how did X do Y?" question.

Comment: @Paulie_D: That is true of every question on this site; if the information wasn't somewhere, no one would ever be able to answer.

Comment: @R_Kapp I think that Pauulie doesn't include the minds of the developers or familiar with the internals.

Comment: @Braiam: How did those developers *become* familiar with the internals? Osmosis, or through documentation available *somewhere*?

Comment: @R_Kapp they wrote it, or had access to the internal mails?

Comment: @Braiam: So, by that logic, then, only questions that can only be answered by implementers of a library are valid on SO? After all, everything else is available *somewhere*. At the leasr, something like language standards would answer just about everything

Comment: @R_Kapp what logic? I'm just interpreting Paulie reasoning. You are reading too much.

Comment: @Braiam: And I am saying that said reasoning *makes no sense*.